# PHPUnit Fixtures stopped loading in cakephp 4

Tags: testing, cakephp, phpunit, fixtures

I have my test for a few months but today I run then and they are not working anymore (I tried them last week and they worked). I'm using PHPUnit to test my Cakephp project, until today it worked but I installed it in another VM and it's not working anymore.(I can't use th old one anymore). The phpunit version is 8.5.2.

It gives the following error:

```
App\Test\TestCase\Controller\CommentControllerTest::testDeleteUnauthenticatedFail
UnexpectedValueException: Could not find fixture `app.Comment`.

/var/www/html/savepets/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureHelper.php:90
/var/www/html/savepets/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/TruncateStrategy.php:51
/var/www/html/savepets/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/TestCase.php:301
/var/www/html/savepets/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/TestCase.php:249
phpvfscomposer:///var/www/html/savepets/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:97
```

Line 39 is parent::setUp();

An example of fixture:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Test\Fixture;

use Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\TestFixture;

/**
 * CommentFixture
 */
class CommentFixture extends TestFixture
{
    /**
     * Table name
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $table = 'comment';
    /**
     * Init method
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function init(): void
    {
        $this->records = [
            [
                'comment_date' => '2022-11-09 21:13:02',
                'message' => 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',
                'publication_id' => 1,
                'user_id' => 1
            ],
        ];
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

An the test (all of them fail):

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Test\TestCase\Controller;

use App\Controller\CommentController;
use Cake\TestSuite\IntegrationTestTrait;
use Cake\TestSuite\TestCase;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;

/**
 * App\Controller\CommentController Test Case
 *
 * @uses \App\Controller\CommentController
 */
class CommentControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    use IntegrationTestTrait;

    /**
     * Fixtures
     *
     * @var array<string>
     */
    protected $fixtures = [
        'app.Comment',
        'app.User',
        'app.Publication',
        'app.PublicationHelp',
        'app.PublicationAdoption',
        'app.PublicationStray',

    ];

    /**
     * Test add method
     *
     * @return void
     * @uses \App\Controller\CommentController::add()
     */
    public function testAdd(): void
    {
        $this->session([
            'Auth' => [
                    'id' => 1,
                    'DNI_CIF' => '22175395Z',
                    'name' => 'Prueba',
                    'lastname' => 'Prueba Prueba',
                    'username' => 'Pruebatesting',
                    'password' => 'prueba',
                    'email' => 'prueba@gmail.com',
                    'phone' => '639087621',
                    'birth_date' => '1999-12-14',
                    'role' => 'admin',
                    'addres_id' => 1
                
            ]
        ]);
        $this->get('comment/add/1/1/Help');
        $this->assertResponseOk();//accesible

        $data=[
            'comment_date' => '2022-11-09 21:13:02',
            'message' => 'Loremcomment ipsum dolor sit amet',
            'publication_id' => 1,
            'user_id' => 1
        ];
        $this->enableCsrfToken();
        $this->post('comment/add/1/1/Help',$data);
        $this->assertRedirect(['controller' => 'PublicationHelp',1, 'action' => 'view',]);//redirige porque es correcto

        $animal = TableRegistry::get('Comment');

        $query = $animal->find()->where(['message' => $data['message']]);

        $this->assertEquals(1,$query->count());//se añadio

    }

    public function testAddUnauthenticatedFail(): void
    {
        $this->enableCsrfToken();
        $this->get('comment/add/1/1/Help');
        $this->assertRedirectContains('/user/login');//se necesita estar logeado por eso redirige a login

    }


}
```

Can't someone tell my why it's giving this error?

app.php is like this:

```
'test' => ['host' =>'localhost',
'className' => Connection::class,
'driver' => Mysql::class,
'persistent' => false,
'timezone' => 'UTC',
//'encoding' => 'utf8mb4',
'flags' => [],
'cacheMetadata' => true,'
quoteIdentifiers' => false,
'log' => false,
//'init' => ['SET GLOBAL innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0'],],],
```

Comment: Start by debugging the `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureHelper.php` file and check what [**the `$className` variable**](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/4.4.13/src/TestSuite/Fixture/FixtureHelper.php#L89) holds.